# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'zipbean' available as request attribute

Tags: jsp

*can someone help me about this error*

*index.jsp*

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="links.jsp"/> 
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/welcome.js"></script>
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Customer" method="POST" modelAttribute="zipbean">
<input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" class="form-control search ui-autocomplete" onkeypress=" return validate(event)" onkeydown="getData('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ZipController/autoComplete');" />
<form:button path="zipone" class="btn btn-success">Get a Quote</form:button>
</center>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

*CustomerController*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Customer")
public class CustomerController 
{
    @Autowired
    ZipDao zipDao;
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String init(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse responce,ModelMap model)
        {
            System.out.println("customer page started");
            ZipBean zipbean=new ZipBean();
            model.addAttribute("zipbean", zipbean);
            return "customer";
        }
}
```

> And i having customer page with some textboxes to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you should replace the

```
<input type="text" id="zip" name="zip"
```

with

```
<form:input type="text" id="zip" path="zip"
```

to make it part of the Spring Bean

Note that the `name` attribute became `path` as part of the adapation to the spring tag

Also, make sure that the `ZipBean` class has a `private String zip;` + a `getZip()` and `setZip(String zip)` method

Finally, make sure that the matching controller that will handle the POST request has the correct `@ModelAttribute` but I suppose that you ask why your jsp won't load in the first place

Comment: what if there is select attribute in same jsp. do i have to add form:select?

Comment: yup - have a look at the Spring docs but the syntax is 99% similar to classic tags :) Mostly name=path in <input> attributes